# Ruby on rails raw tag inside a link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have been having some problems with variables inside `link_to` tags, which only get to work when wrapped in a `raw`.

What does `raw` actually mean? Is it a good practice to use it to wrap strings and variables inside a tag?

Comment: You've got two questions here, one of which is general and googleable, and the other is just general and opinion based.  I think you would be better off explaining the specific problem you are having, which might be solveable without using `raw`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the official Rails [`raw`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/OutputSafetyHelper.html#method-i-raw) documentation:

> This method outputs without escaping a string. Since escaping tags is now default, this can be used when you don't want Rails to automatically escape tags. This is not recommended if the data is coming from the user's input.

It's not a good practice to use `raw` because it bypasses the default Rails input sanitization. Use it only if you know what you are doing.

If you need to use raw HTML inside the link to, you can also pass it as a block.

```
<%= link_to root_url do %>
  <span>My link</span>
<% end %>
```

Another alternative is to use the Rails helpers which sanitizes the input.

```
<%= link_to content_tag(:span, "Unsafe input"), root_url %>
```

Comment: Please explain what sanitation is in your answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

`raw` outputs without escaping the string

[raw docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/RawOutputHelper/raw)

Answer (score 0):

Why you had problems, [link_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) helper accepts block as argument, you can insert any content inside `link_to` helper

For example:

```
<%= link_to 'link' do %>
  <p> First paragraph </p>
  <%= 'ruby string' %>
<% end %>
```

Will produce

```
<a href='/link'>
  <p> First paragraph </p>
  ruby string
</a>
```